# Как при нажатии на кнопку добавить к тексту класс?

Tags: javascript, html, css, bootstrap

Только учусь и совсем не знаю JS 
У меня есть:

```
<script>
        function SubscribeFunction() {
            document.getElementById("subscribe-button").innerHTML = "Thanks ♥";
        }
    </script>
```

Это при нажатии на кнопку просто меняется текст. Как можно добавить к этому тексту класс?

Comment: Что значит: "добавить к этому ТЕКСТУ класс"? Имеется ввиду значек "класс" из одноклассников? Или же все же нужно добавить класс элементу с id="subscribe-button"?

Comment: непонятно что вы под классом у текста подразумеваете.

Answer (score 5):

```
<script>
        function SubscribeFunction() {
            document.getElementById("subscribe-button").innerHTML = "Thanks ♥";
            document.getElementById("subscribe-button").classList.add('className');
        }
</script>
```

className - поменять на свое

Более детально с работой класса вы можете почитать [здесь](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Element/classList)

Лучшим вариантом реализации вышеописанного кода будет:

```
 <script>
            function SubscribeFunction() {
                var subscribeElement = document.getElementById("subscribe-button");
                subscribeElement.innerHTML = "Thanks ♥";
                subscribeElement.classList.add('className');
            }
 </script>
```

Answer (score 3):

Добавляем элементу класс `myClass`:

```
document.getElementById('subscribe-button').classList.add('myClass');
```